# Exact equations & integrating factors

Tags: partial-differential-equations, improper-integrals

Show that the following equation is exact or can be made exact,  hence solve it:
$$(\cos^2x+y\sin2x)y'+y^2=0$$
Here, $M=y^2$ and $N=(\cos^2x+y\sin2x)$
$$M_y=2y$$
$$N_x=-2\cos x \sin x +2y\cos 2x$$
After this I can't understand how to find the Integrating factor. Please help.

Comment: Will writing $N_x=-2\cos x \sin x +2y\cos 2x$ as $N_x=-\ sin2x+2y\ (1-2cos^2x)$ help? This can be simplified as $N_x=-\sin 2x +\ 2y - 4y\cos^2x$

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but then what to do?...how to calculate the integrating factor?

Comment: Well I don't want to give the whole answer. So I'll give a hint - We need an I.F. such that $M_y=N_x$. So, we multiply the integrating factor on both sides of the equation(the I.F. term will be multiplied in the derivative, so it's derivative will also be there) and isolate the terms (on the LHS) which contain the I.F. solely, like the I.F. itself or it's partial derivative wrt x. On the RHS, you will get a simple trigonometric term and the resulting equation will be another differential equation. Solve that, you'll get the I.F. with ease. The I.F. after solving will come out to be $sec^2x$.

Comment: Thank you for this hint

Comment: No problem! Glad to help! :D